# migrate existing h2 db to mysql in WSO2APIM 1.8.0

Tags: mysql, h2, wso2-api-manager

To convert h2 database to Mysql I used SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin .
while copying the h2 database tables to the Mysql database it gives following error.
it is Primary key use in h2 db and this constraint cannot convert to Mysql.

> 2015-05-18 10:24:43,590 [DBCopy Executor Thread] ERROR
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.dbcopy.CopyProgressMonitor  - SQL
>   Error code = 1170 sql = CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONSTRAINT_INDEX_73 ON
>   AM_API (    API_PROVIDER, API_NAME, API_Venter code hereERSION )
>
> (Bind variable values: WSO2 Identity Server)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT
>   column 'API_PROVIDER' used in key specification without a key length

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to use the MySQL script which was shipped with WSO2 APIM 1.8 to create the database tables. You can find those scripts (mysql.sql) from /dbscripts/ folder and /dbscripts/apimgt folder.

Comment: To add on to the above asnwer, donot use -Dsetup option to create the database tables, because it will also create data and when you use squirrel copy, you will end up in lot of errors. I lost many hours resolving these issues.

Directly run the mysql.sql from the dbscripts to create the empty tables, and then do the copy

Answer (score 0):

make sure you copy the mysql-driver to  **[product_hoeme]/repository/components/lib**
as well